# Implementing UIScrollView Methods when Subclassing UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm having problems controlling the scrolling within a `UITextView` that I'm using, so I've opted to create my own subclass.

I've got a very basic question about providing implementations for some of the `UIScrollView` superclass methods.

Here's my skeleton code for the `UITextView` subclass:

```
@interface PastedTextView : UITextView
@end

@implementation PastedTextView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"scrollRectToVisible");
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"setContentOffset");
}

- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"zoomToRect");
}

@end
```

When will those `UIScrollView` methods be called? Only from my own client code? Or will they be called by the framework?

**Update:**

The reason I've asked this is because I'm having the following problem: I'm programatically adding text to the `UITextView` (from the pasteboard). When I do so, if the textview has scrolled such that the top of the content is no longer in view, the text view scrolls back to the top after the new text has been appended.

I'm not explicitly triggering this scroll, so it's happening within the framework.

I haven't found anything in Apple's documentation that describes this behaviour. So, I've been trying to locate the source of the scrolling so that I can avoid it...

When this scroll happens, none of the above methods are called. Incidentally, neither is `UITextView`s `scrollRangeToVisible` method (I've tried adding that method to the subclass implementation). I can't figure out why that implicit scroll back to the top is happening and I want to prevent it...

Answer (score 0):

If you override these `UIScrollView` methods as shown, any caller (be it your code, or the system's) will hit your implementation instead of the builtin `UIScrollView` one. If you want to take advantage of the system implementation, you can always call super.

```
- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super zoomToRect:rect animated:animated];
    NSLog(@"zoomToRect");
}
```

Comment: so the problem I'm having: I'm programatically adding text to the `UITextView` (from the pasteboard). When I do so, if the textview has scrolled such that the top of the content is no longer in view, the text view scrolls back to the top after appending the new text. When this happens, none of the above methods are called. Incidentally, neither is `UITextView`s `scrollRangeToVisible` method (if I add that to the subclass implementation). I can't figure out why that implicit scroll back to the top is happening...